# save filename of extracted tar file to variable

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, tar

Is there a way to save the extracted filename to a variable when using tar?

for example, my tar command is:

```
tar --extract --file something.tgz
```

I want to do an `echo` afterwards to see what the directory name is that just got untared. This will be dynamic so I cant hard code.

Answer (score 0):

Before extract you can test archive and get the filenames inside:

```
tar tzvf something.tgz
```

to assign it to variable use syntax:

```
var=$(command....)
```

when you have filename with path to get only the directory you can use this command

```
dirname $var
```

(variable from previous command)